# adb shell command

Tags: android, adb

I want to `push image` to `sdcard` via `adb shell command` which are stay in my d:\folder
 i want to see it in emulator not on device.
can you help me on this 
Thanks
Nik

Comment: possible duplicate of [store file in SD card adb shell emulator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6716329/store-file-in-sd-card-adb-shell-emulator)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you trying to do

```
adb push d:\folder\myimage.jpg /sdcard/myimage.jpg
```

Depending on your Android version, it could also be `/mnt/sdcard/myimage.jpg`.

If you want to put it where you other images are, you could push it to `mnt/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/myimage.jpg`.

Comment: It should. Did you put it into `/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/Camera`? On some HTC phones, it's `/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/100MEDIA`. It's moot though, Android will scan the entire SD card for images. So if it doesn't work, it's probably because the media scanner didn't realize that you snuck an image in via adb. Option 1: Unmount and remount your phone. Option 2: Reset your phone. Then, after the re-scan, the image should appear.

Comment: i havent any phone. i want to store it in emulator

Comment: from where i can see that image(view image)

Comment: can you navigate me for emulator